Is it possible to retrieve lists of HDF5 file, group, dataset, and attribute in Golang
I'm currently working on developing data reading and writing for HDF5 files in Golang. I've consulted the library documentation and managed to successfully implement writing operations. Now, I need to read the stored HDF5 file and display it either in a CLI or a web interface. However, I couldn't find a way to do it using the access functions provided in Golang.
Here's what I have so far:
fname := "example.h5"
file, _ := hdf5.OpenFile(fname)

// Open the 'ImageData' group
group, err := hdf5.OpenDataGroup(&file.CommonFG, "ImageData")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to open group 'ImageData': %s", err)
}
defer group.Close()

attr1 := group.GetAttribute("name")

fmt.Println(attr1)

Both OpenDataGroup and GetAttribute are custom functions based on HDF5.
Firstly, I want to determine what groups exist within the file. However, there's no function in Golang to list the groups and datasets under a file.
Secondly, I want to print out the metadata (attributes) stored in the file, group, and dataset. But, similarly, there's no function to retrieve a list of attributes.
Currently, I can only access attributes if I know they exist, like so:
attr1 := group.GetAttribute("name")

However, I want the program to work without prior knowledge of what attributes exist in the file. Because I want to display lists of groups, datasets, and attributes to the user. But I can't achieve this with the current approach.
I'm still searching for a solution, but if you have any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate them. Ultimately, I want to:
Print out a list of groups and datasets existing within the file.
Print out a list of attributes.
I'll post this on Stack Overflow once it's ready. Thank you!
I've searched through all the available Golang libraries, but couldn't find a solution. Golang functions require explicit names for files, groups, and datasets, which is impractical as I can't input each name individually. On one hand, I find Golang libraries very limited. I often feel that they are not suitable for providing services to users. However, I still hope to develop using Golang.
